# Azure DevOps: In Azure SQL Publish Deployment, Missing values for the following SqlCmd variables:env master

Tags: sql-server, sql, azure, continuous-operation

In Azure SQL Publish Deployment, An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue. Missing values for the following SqlCmd variables:env master. The Azure SQL DACPAC task failed. SqlPackage.exe exited with code 1

1. DevOps Build: SqlProj Build success.
2. DevOps Release: Getting the above mentioned error.

**Try 1**: Have added the variable master with value master in release pipeline. Not helped.

**Try 2**:Have added the variable master with value master in build pipeline itself. Not helped too.

Answer (score 2):

In your pipeline, for the SQL Server Database deploy task. Add the following to "Additional Arguments" box. This way the parameter will be mapped when SqlPackage.exe runs the parameterized script.

/v:master=master

Comment: Many thanks for this answer